# Clean way to generate HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

**First of All I can't put all my elements in ONE ROW ONLY (all inline)** I'm trying to generate one row of elements inside `envVariablesDiv`. I did all the html using javascript in my attempt and it's a huge mess and confusing.

Is there a simpler way to add rows of my elements everytime I click the button? I also need to be able to delete the row when I click delete.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <div class="top20 content-form">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="addEnv"><button class="btn btn-primary">add</button></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <label id="addEnv" class="label label-secondary pointer-label"><span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span> Add environment variable</label>
      <div id="envVariablesDiv">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Text</span>
          <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="msg" placeholder="Additional Info">
        </div>
       <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Text</span>
          <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="msg" placeholder="Additional Info">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS I done: The styling is different now. I want to use input group.

```
 $('#addEnv').click(function () {
   $('#envVariablesDiv').append('<div class="col-sm-5 top10"><label for="envName" class="control-label">Name</label><input id="envName" class="form-control" name="envName" type="text" placeholder="e.g. name1" /></div>' +
       '<div class="col-sm-5 top10"><label for=envVar class="control-label">Variable</label><input class="form-control" id="envVar" type="text" name="envVar" placeholder="e.g. var1" /></div><div class="col-sm-2 top10"><button class="btn btn-danger"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button></div>');
});
```

Comment: Bootstrap includes a grid system you can use to place the inputs all on one row: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid. If you want to delete elements on click of the button you'll need to write some JS code to do that.

Comment: Could you include the JS you have so far?

Comment: done. But I want the input group above

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but isn't there a way to copy and paste multiple html elements? I dunno but this seems like a huge mess for a simple code.